# How to query all documents user has access to in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to figure out how to display all documents user has access to but i am either getting no documents at all or undefined user.docs if person is not logged in.

In Meteor, my user has

```
 docs: {
  "xxx1",
  "xxx2",
  "xxx3"
 }
```

etc (it may be limitless number of ids.
How to query mongo to find all documents that have id = user.docs? (return array of docs).

Answer (score 0):

'If a person is not logged in'? I'm assuming this is server side?

Are you trying to grab 'docs' off of Meteor.user() ? 
That only works on the current logged in user.

Server side mongodb query on a user:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({_id: '<userId string here>'},{fields: {docs: 1}});
```

Should give you:

```
{_id: '<userId string here>', docs: {...docs here...}}
```

Be careful with user data!

EDIT:

If you are trying to get docs that match the doc ids from a user object, you would ideally rearrange your data structure to

```
docs: ['docId', 'docId']    <---this may be your main problem
```

Then it would be:

```
var userDocsIds = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: '<userId string here>'},{fields: {docs: 1}});

var userDocs = Docs.find({_id: {$in: userDocsIds.docs}}).fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$in` operator to find `_ids` in an array:

```
const docIds = Meteor.users.findOne(id).docs;
const myDocs = Docs.find({_id: {$in: docIds }});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried both and ended up using

```
docs = getDocsForUser(user); //print array of docs
return docs.find({_id: {$in: docs}})
```